# McCree's Deadeye Damage

Tags: overwatch

Does McCree's Deadeye damage increase beyond the killshot if you charge it for longer duration than the killshot?

Like for example, if a McCree ults, and holds the ult there for the full duration before releasing it, does it deal more damage as compared to just firing it off the moment he lines up a killshot?

Edit: If McCree manages to accumulate enough damage with his Deadeye, can he potentially destroy Reinhardt's shield and kill the targets behind?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, yes it does. It **adds 170 damage for every second** you are charging. You can charge it for 6 seconds which adds to 1020 damage in total - per shot.

Edit: Apparently he can break the Shield and the Damage stacks onto it.

- Mcree perspective: https://streamable.com/ewr8?t=23.9
- Reihnardt perspective: https://streamable.com/olim?t=5.9

Comment: Does that mean he can break a rein's shiled after charging for some time if there are a lot of players in sight?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I have no idea and suggest you ask it. It makes sense to stack the damage on the shield, as the damage is per shot, but I have no idea.

Comment: editing question

Comment: @KimMinseo editing answer

Comment: alright thx for the answer :)

Comment: @KimMinseo: I have tryed this with my team in the open beta phase. I was Reinhard and a full team hid behind my shield while McCree charged his deadeye. My shield got broken + 3 of our mates died, while I was like having 100HP left as Reinhard. So it have probabbly been the damage of the 2 suriving Heroes which broke the shield + a part of my bullet(!) and the other 3 heroes received their deadshot.

Comment: I'm interested: Is the 170 damage per second purely time related? So a bad timing Roadhoag entering the view of McCree for the first time just in deadeyes last second, kills him or deals him 170 dmg?

Comment: @Zaibis Yes, the ROadhoag will die if the charge has been up for 5 seconds but he only appears for the last 1.

Comment: I downvoted this, as I tryed it out jsut right now and genuily can say this is wrong.

Comment: @ИвоНедев The Roadhog will not die if he moves into Deadeye during the last second. The charge time of 170 damage per second is independent for each locked in target, and only while that target remains in line of sight. If you move out of LoS, Deadeye's damage stops ramping until you move back in.